# JavaScript not preventing the default function for audio player

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio-player

So I've been following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtZCMTtP-0Y), and for the life of me, I cannot figure out why my code is doing the default new page with my audio files and not preventing the default. Once I figure that part out, I should be able to test the event listener at the bottom of my code when my song ends.

JavaScript

```
audioPlayer();
function audioPlayer() {
    var currentSong = 0;
    $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[0];
    $("#playlist li a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = this;
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
        $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
        currentSong = $(this).parent().index();
        $(this).parent.addClass("current-song");
    });

    $("#audioPlayer")[0].addEventListener("ended", function(){
        alert("hi");    
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<section>
        <script>
            audioPlayer();
        </script>
        <audio src="" id="audioPlayer" controls>
            Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 audio player!
        </audio>
        <ul id="playlist">
            <li class="current-song"><a href="All_American_Reject_Move_Along.mp3">Move Along</a></li>
            <li><a href="Far_From_Home.m4a">Far From Home</a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure $("#playlist li a").click() executed once page is loaded.

```
    function initAudioPlayer() {
        var currentSong = 0;
        $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = $("#playlist li a")[0];
        $("#playlist li a").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#audioPlayer")[0].src = this;
            $("#audioPlayer")[0].play();
            $("#playlist li").removeClass("current-song");
            currentSong = $(this).parent().index();
            $(this).parent.addClass("current-song");
        });

        $("#audioPlayer")[0].addEventListener("ended", function(){
            alert("hi");    
        });
    }

$(document).ready(function() {
   initAudioPlayer();
})
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! Another issue was declaring the function at very top. I took out the audioPlayer(); from the top of the line before the function was created. That fixed it.

Comment: No problem @HanSolo0001. Be careful when you are not awaiting for document ready for the initial script since the dom may not be rendered from the server yet when your script is executed. Then the events may not be registered properly.